# css3 multiple shadows from different rules

Tags: css, dropshadow

Is it possible for css3 multiple shadows to be accumilated from different css rules / classes ?

i.e.

```
.multipleShadows {box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px black, 40px -30px lime}
```

will create two shadows for the element, black and lime.

but I want to have two different classes - one for blackShadow and one for limeShadow

```
.blackShadow {box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px black}
.limeShadow {box-shadow: 40px -30px lime}
```

and have both applied to a single element that has both classes.

```
<div class="blackShadow limeShadow">my div</div>
```

Can this be done? 
Are there alternate ways that can achieve this goal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using an extra div placed inside the original div and applied the second shadow class to the internal div.

```
<div class="blackShadow"><div class="limeShadow"> my div</div></div>
```

This was chosen becuase it keeps the definitions of the shadow classes separate and still allows me to show both the shadows at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Write like this:

```
.blackShadow.limeShadow {box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px black, 40px -30px lime}
```

Comment: yep, this is a last choice and is not any different then using `.blackAndLime` as a different selector because it does not allow for reuse of the basic shadow definitions.

Comment: or actually it will not even be my last choice as I will probably prefer to add another internal div and apply the second shadow class to it.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't exactly a better method to do this other than make a separate class like `.doubleShadow` or to write another style for `.blackShadow .limeShadow`.

You can use **LESS** and make a mixin which you can then implement. That will be a better option if you are looking for a different solution.

Regardless of that I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/wxQtt/) of what you have given in the question.